# How to test a parameter of a function defined by generics for null correctly

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that takes generics like this:

```
public class Foo<T> {

  public IActionResult MyClass(T id) {
   if (id == null)
     //do stuff
   else
     //do something else
  }
}
```

I notice that .net Core MVC automatically fills in the parameter if it is missing. So if someone would instantiate my class with `new Foo<Guid>`, my parameter `id` would never equal null, but would equal `Guid.Empty`.

I've thought of two solutions, but I'm lost at how to implement either one.

1. Specify that type parameter `T` must be a nullable type, like `Guid?` so I can use `if (id.HasValue)` to check if the id parameter was supplied. Is this even possible?
2. Check the id against the type's default value. The code below does not compile (Error message says "Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'TId' and 'TId')

`if (id == null || id == default(TId));`

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: `Object.Equals(id, null)` will compile. And it'll return true for `Guid? id = null;`

Comment: `if (id != null && !id.Equals(default(T))`?

Comment: thank you mm8, I just discovered the same thing. If you post the same thing as an answer, I'll select your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't contraint `T` to be a reference or a value type, you can check whether it's `null` or equal to the default value of `T`:

```
if (id != null && !id.Equals(default(T))
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using was :

```
if (id == null || Object.Equals(id, default(TId)))
 //id was not supplied
else 
 //id was supplied
```

Comment: Be aware that this can lead to interesting surprises. `default(int)` is `0`, for example, but `0` is of course an integer value that might be explicitly supplied. I don't have much experience with MVC, but your parameters should probably be explicitly nullable there if possible.

Comment: Thank you. Your information is very valid! Luckily, for our use case this does not pose a problem, but it is a valid concern you raise!